# SwiftUI View permissions best practice?

Tags: ios, authorization, swift-language

I am currently developing an iOS application where there are options on the screen to edit and delete a list. Only the user who created this list can edit or delete it. I am struggling to determine the best practice for hiding these options if the list does not belong to the individual that created it.

Please keep in mind that the API that is being consumed from this app is also mine and I can structure the response and request payloads however I see fit.

My first question to myself is whether to make this determination client-side, server-side, or both? My current options to make this decision are as follows.

- I can create a separate view without those options and have the navigation view route to that view if the list does not belong to the current viewer. I would prefer this the least so I don't clutter up my project with views.
- I can create some sort of flag on the API call that, once returned, will let the view know whether or not to display these edit and delete options.
- Create a separate API endpoint that returns a true or false value whether or not it should display these edit and delete options.

I am not familiar with permissions/authorization structures within Swift/iOS environments so would love some feedback if possible. What would the best practice be here?

Answer (score 1):

Create a GUID the first time your app is launched and store it in user defaults (or better in the keychain, so it survives if the app is removed from the phone and downloaded again). When anyone creates a list and stores it on the server, attach the GUID. When anyone downloads the list, they also download the GUID and you allow editing if the GUIDs match.